# Include a button to "like" my page in a post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

I need to get more likes to my Facebook page, problem is that I don't know how to make a post from where people can like my page. My boss sent me a screenshot from Facebook iPhone's app.

[image: Se]

*See how you can like the page?*

I don't know if this is a sponsored post or not but my question is: are there any non-paid ways to include a button to "like" my page in a post?

Comment: I believe this is a sponsored feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I've researched this (as I wanted the same think) it was a paid feature. You have the ability to promote your page by paying which gives you this feature.

Other than that, if you want to promote your page without paying you should look at alternative options (like similar pages and engage in conversations and mutual advertising using your page name, engage in discussions and post your page on similar interest groups, add link to your facebook page from your actual web page if any, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Add "?ref=bookmarks" to the end of your page URL.

```
https://www.facebook.com/YOURpage?ref=bookmarks
```

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Please take the [tour]. And take a look to [help/answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). From the second link: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better" :).